# powershell: how to escape all regex characters from a string

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, escaping

I am wondering if there is a better way to escape regex characters in powershell, I know C# has Regex.Escape, but I'm not sure if powershell has its own method...

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
$escapedStr = $regexStr -replace "\+","\+" -replace "\[","\[" -replace "\]","\]" -replace "\(","\(" -replace "\)","\)"
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

PowerShell can call the exact same method:

```
[Regex]::Escape($regexStr)
```

But you could even improve your replacement by using just a single regex replace:

```
$regexStr -replace '[[+*?()\\.]','\$&'
```

However, I probably still missed a few metacharacters from that character class, so just use the `[regex]::Escape` method.