# Using PowerShell to replace string that contains + in the string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell do a simple find and replace.  Essentially, I used to have some support files in a directory with the same name of a "master" file.  All but one of those support files are no longer necessary.  The "master" file has a text reference to the path of the other file.  What I want to do is modify this path in the "master" file to remove the deleted directory.

For example, let's say I have the file `C:\Temp\this+that.txt`  I used to have `C:\Temp\this+that\this+that.dat` that has now been moved to `C:\Temp\this+that.dat`

`C:\Temp\this+that.txt` has a line like this:

```
/temp/this+that/this+that.dat
```

I would like this line to become:

```
/temp/this+that.dat
```

I have lots of these files that a batch file is moving.  Everything is working fine using the powershell command below for all file names that do NOT contain a plus `+` sign.  For those files, the call below does not work.

```
powershell -Command "(gc '!CURRENT_FILE!') -replace '/!BASE_NAME!/', '/' | Set-Content '!CURRENT_FILE!'"
```

For the example above, `CURRENT_FILE` would be `C:\Temp\this+that.txt` and `BASE_NAME` would be `this+that`

Can anyone help me with why this isn't working for file names that contain a plus `+` sign?

Comment: The problem here is that you're treating `!BASE_NAME!` as a regular expression. I don't know my way around PowerShell, but [this answer looks like it might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651862/powershell-how-to-escape-all-regex-characters-from-a-string#23651909). Basically you'll need to escape all characters with special Regex-meaning before interpolating it into the expression.

Comment: @ma_il is exactly right. The '+' character is a special character in RegEx, so you will need to escape it. `"(gc '!CURRENT_FILE!') -replace [regex]::escape('/!BASE_NAME!/'), '/' | Set-Content '!CURRENT_FILE!'"`

Answer (score 2):

@ma_il is exactly right. The '+' character is a special character in RegEx, so you will need to escape it.

```
powershell -Command "(gc '!CURRENT_FILE!') -replace [regex]::escape('/!BASE_NAME!/'), '/' | Set-Content '!CURRENT_FILE!'"
```